# How hard is deciding the existence of Red-Blue perfect matching?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

Two-colorable perfect matching problem is to decide whether a graph has coloring with two colors such that each node has exactly one neighbor the same color as itself. The problem was proven to be NP-complete by [Schaefer](http://aleteya.cs.buap.mx/~jlavalle/papers/complexity/p216-schaefer.pdf). It remains NP-complete even for planar cubic graphs.

I am interested in a variant where we want to decide whether input graph has coloring with two colors such each node has exactly one neighbor colored differently from itself. I call this Red-Blue perfect matching problem. I don't know whether this is a known problem.

> How hard is deciding the existence of Red-Blue perfect matching?

Comment: Another way of stating this problem would be to ask whether the given graph has a perfect matching which is also a cut.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Mikhail noted, the problem was called Perfect Matching Cut in literatures. It was proved to be NP-complete in the following paper (see Theorem 1 on page 5), with a reduction from monotone 1-in-3-SAT:

[Pinar Heggernes, Jan Arne Telle. Partitioning Graphs Into Generalized Dominating Sets.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d44c/a18638eadeeb17b69f657cfa06c313646b8c.pdf)